# Django: Get flat value for an item in a QuerySet / dictionary

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, iteration

I have tried many things, to include `itervalues()`, `values_list()`, `values()`, but I cannot seem to get the value ONLY for a object in a dictionary I have created.  Here is the following code in my view:

```
choices = Choice.objects.filter(question_id=q.id).order_by('order')

for c in choices:
    new_c = dict(choice_id=c.id, question_id=c.question_id, choice=c.choice, order=g.order,
                         text=c.text, skip_to=c.skip_to)

    if new_c['skip_to']:
        new_s = dict(question_id=q.id, skip_to=c.skip_to, page_number=0)
                skip_to_list.append(new_s)

        new_q['choices'].append(new_c)
```

When I print this I get:

```
[{'page_number': 0, 'skip_to': <Group: 5>, 'question_id': 1}, {'page_number': 0, 'skip_to': <Group: 5>, 'question_id': 2}, {'page_number': 0, 'skip_to': <Group: 5>, 'question_id': 3}]
```

As you can see, `skip_to` has a value of `<Group: 5>`.  In my model, the value of `skip_to` is equal to a fk in my Group object.  I just want the value to equal `5`.  I don't want the Group.  But this is the only item I want to have a flat value, I don't want the entire `choice` object to have flat value.

Sorry, still new to how to navigate and iterate through lists and dictionaries, but after hours of searching, I figured I would just ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 5 is the `id` (primary key) of `Group` model, you can do an assignment as follows:

```
skip_to=c.skip_to.pk
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can't believe I overlooked that. So simple!